# Dispatcher Pattern for Delegating Tasks from a Central Controller

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am writing some code to listen to events from Kafka (in Java). Here's the design:

1. A central controller that listens to events from a particular topic.
2. Based on the message type, invoke an appropriate controller.
3. The controller in turn invokes its handler to perform the appropriate action.

What would be the ideal design pattern that I can use for the above scenario? I tried using the visitor pattern. Is it the right choice here?

Comment: Why do you need a design pattern?

Comment: @jaco0646 I thought there might be a design pattern to handle such scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scenario looks to be a very good case for `Strategy` design pattern. You will be having different strategy depending on message type. At run-time, depending on the message type, respective strategy will do the needful work.